# does apache shiro supports user groups concept?

Tags: authorization, shiro

I'm reading the `shiro` documentation and never found any signs that `shiro` supports user groups concept on API level.

I would have expected that `Subject.java` would have such methods as `getUserGroups`, but it doesn't. For example, if I write some application which aims to work with numerous authentication systems, when the user creates some object, I would like to make it visible for all users in the object creator's groups, and to do it in an authentication provider agnostic way, using some facade API, like shiro Subject.

But it's looks like I can't doing this using `shiro` api, is this correct?

How do you support user groups concept in multi-auth applications ?

Should I write some `UserGroupAwareSubject` extension ?

Comment: is the answer sufficient?  If so, you should award it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiro as of 1.2 does not have a Group concept in its API - it has the notion of Roles and Permissions.

This is not a problem if you have only Roles or you can use your Group names as what Shiro calls Roles (i.e. realm.hasRole(roleIdentifier, authzInfo) uses your Group name as the 'roleIdentifier').

If you have both Role and Group concepts in your application, you will probably not easily be able to use subject.hasRole for checking both.  If you'd like this as a feature, please open a [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO).

Two options for this though if you want to make it work is:

1. Have one Realm where realm.hasRole calls check against your Roles and another Realm where realm.hasRole calls checks against your Groups.
2. Use one Realm to perform both and just prefix the strings you use for group checks with a recognizable token, e.g.:

   ```
   subject.hasRole("group:myGroupName");
   ```

   Then your realm can check to see if has that prefix, and if so, do a group check, and if not, do a role check.

These options aside, what many people do in this case is ignore Role and Group checks entirely and instead rely on (the more powerful) permission checks in code:

```
subject.isPermitted("document:1234:read");
```

Then your Realm can check both the Subject *and* any of its assigned Groups or Roles to see if they imply that permission.  If so, then you don't need any Group or Role checks at all because your code relies on permissions instead of the (potentially volatile and numerous) Groups/Roles concept.

There are some good reasons [why permissions are probably better than Role or Group checks](https://www.stormpath.com/blog/new-rbac-resource-based-access-control), but if you feel otherwise and would still like Groups represented in the `Subject` API any, please do open a feature request.

Regards,

Les

Comment: Is it possible to give restrictions to permissions, eg. to restrict "read" for specific user altough the role of the user is allowed ?